# #VALUE! Error on Cell Containing Successfully Compiled VBA Function

Tags: excel, vba, integration

I am using VBA to integrate in Excel. I have a multitude of variables necessary to the integration process in an organized table on the sheet that will be changed as needed. I have written the following code to accomplish this and have successfully debugged said code so that it is compiling without error.

```
Dim dIdt As Range
Dim Isnp As Range
Dim Tau As Range

Dim A As Range
Dim B As Range
Dim C As Range
Dim D As Range


Function Iscr(t)
Set dIdt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F11").Value
Set Isnp = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F14").Value
Set Tau = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F13").Value
Iscr = (dIdt * t) + (Isnp * (Exp((-t) / Tau)))
End Function

Function Econd1A(t)
Set A = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B17").Value
Set B = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B18").Value
Set C = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B19").Value
Set D = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B20").Value
Econd1A = A + (B * (Log(Iscr(t)))) + (C * (Iscr(t))) + (D * (Iscr(t) ^ (1 / 2)) * Iscr(t))
End Function

Function Econd1(x0, t1, t2)

'define range of integral
int_range = t2 - t1

'discretize the integral into n slices dt wide
n = 1000
dt = int_range / n

'initialize variables
ta = t1
tb = ta + dt
Econd1 = x0

'calculate areas using trapezoidal rule

'sum area under curve of each slice
For j = 1 To n
Econd1 = Econd1 + (tb - ta) * (Econd1A(ta) + Econd1A(tb)) / 2
ta = tb
tb = ta + dt
Next

End Function
```

I am now at a loss in regards to debugging as the error does not seem to be VBA related.

The cell's expected output is .0127, but it is instead giving a #VALUE! error.

Comment: You can't `Dim A As Range` and then `Set A = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B17").Value`. You've got multiple instances where you try to `Set` a `Range = something.Value`

Comment: remove all Set it does not need

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin that will not work if the variables are `Dim`med `As Range`. You'd need to remove the `.Value`. Or declare the variables as something other than `Range`, presumably `Double`.

Comment: @BigBen When my declarations are changed to `Double` I receive and "Object Required" error in my Econd1A function.

Comment: @FreshSaladBar what line throws the error? Did you remove all the `Set`?

Comment: @BigBen Upon removing all the `Set` strings, the outcome was the same as the solution provided by @DmitrijHolkin. Unfortunately, that includes the unexpected outcome which leads me to believe there was a mathematical error on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function Iscr(ByVal t As Double) As Double
    Dim dIdt As Double, Isnp As Double, Tau As Double
        dIdt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F11").Value
        Isnp = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F14").Value
        Tau = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F13").Value
        Iscr = (dIdt * t) + (Isnp * (Exp((-t) / Tau)))
End Function

Function Econd1A(ByVal t As Double) As Double
    Dim A As Double, B As Double, C As Double, D As Double
        A = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B17").Value
        B = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B18").Value
        C = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B19").Value
        D = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B20").Value
        Econd1A = A + (B * (Log(Iscr(t)))) + (C * (Iscr(t))) + (D * (Iscr(t) ^ (1 / 2)) * Iscr(t))
End Function

Function Econd1(ByVal x0 As Double, ByVal t1 As Double, ByVal t2 As Double) As Double
Dim int_range As Integer
    int_range = t2 - t1
    n = 1000
    dt = int_range / n
    ta = t1
    tb = ta + dt
    Econd1 = x0
        For j = 1 To n
            sEcond1 = sEcond1 + (tb - ta) * (Econd1A(ta) + Econd1A(tb)) / 2
            ta = tb
            tb = ta + dt
        Next j
Econd1 = sEcond1
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution rids me of the #Value! error, but does not result in the expected outcome, I will double check the math involved.

Comment: #Value beacause you provide not numbers integers or doubles, but provide strings, or using wrong decimal separator for example `.` instead of `,`

Comment: This is a simple question I could just google, but am I supposed to use `,` instead of `.`? As I understood it this is a regional difference and I've never used `,` in a spreadsheet before. Also, after reading your explanation of the issue, I'm curious if it is possible for me to pass the variables as integers and get a different outcome?

Comment: A variable of type Double is more accurate than a variable of type Integer and can also store numbers after the comma. For diff regional you cant use something like `replace(t,".",Application.DecimalSeparator)`

Comment: or better `t = CDbl(Replace(t, ".", Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)))`

Comment: FWIW the "you're providing strings" is a wild unverified assumption. Unless the error is a *type mismatch* upon the assignment of the `Double` values, there is no basis for that claim. The error could just as well be an overflow error caused by the calculations themselves, depending on what values were supplied. Or maybe `B18` contains a `#VALUE` error itself, who knows. Also, UDFs should take all their inputs as parameters, instead of fetching them from a specific worksheet cell.

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin I'm unsure where your suggested line of code should be placed in my existing code.

Comment: @FreshSaladBar unless your cells are formatted as text, nowhere.

Comment: @FreshSaladBar no, it takes a *very, very large number* to overflow a `Double`... admittedly I hadn't looked at the math very carefully, `x ^ 0.5` isn't a likely suspect at all. Basically the run-time error could be *a lot of things* - best course of action IMO is to *debug* the function and step through it line by line to see where it's going wrong. Once you know what's wrong, we can help with fixing it. Dmitrij is correct in that *one possible cause* of errors is that Excel might be storing numbers as text due to the wrong decimal separator being used, but it could be many other things, too.

Answer (score 1):

Excel's calculation engine wraps any errors thrown in a User-Defined Function (UDF - a custom function invoked from a worksheet cell) and yields a `#VALUE` cell error instead of blowing up like broken VBA code normally does. Without any error-handling going on, debugging a UDF can be "fun".

Implement error handling:

```
Public Function MyUDF(args)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    '...code...
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Stop ' halts execution
    Resume 'jumps back to the error-raising statement
End Function
```

Have the *immediate pane* visible (Ctrl+G) in the VBE, then calculate a worksheet that is invoking the UDF, with multiple possible inputs that cover all edge cases - with special attention given to values that can result in *overflow* and *division by zero* errors.

When execution halts at the `Stop` keyword, press F8 to run the `Resume` statement, which will take you straight to the statement that caused the error - from there you can inspect all variables involved, and step through the function line by line to validate your math *as it executes* - and you can move the "current instruction" yellow line back up to an already-executed statement to re-run it, too - just drag the yellow arrow to where you want it to be within the function, or right-click an instruction and select "set next statement".

The error-handling/debugging code could be removed once you *know* the function works as intended and you're ok with it returning a `#VALUE` error given invalid arguments.

Comment: Extremely comprehensive and helpful troubleshooting advice. Thank you.

Comment: @MathieuGuidon When you instruct me to calculate a worksheet invoking the UDF, am I simply making a table of inputs and expected outputs? I'm not sure how the debugging code you provided should actually work with the worksheet involving multiple possible inputs.

Comment: Every single cell containing that function will be invoking it, so if you have 20 cells each calling the UDF once, the function will run 20 times. If 20 cells invoke it twice, the function will run 40 times.

Comment: I'm still unsure what the `myUDF` function will do. When you advise me to test my existing code, I understand and am willing to do the debugging and grunt work myself, I am unfortunately simply unaware of where to begin. Your original post was helpful, I just do not fully understand it.

Comment: I must seem particularly dense by now but how am i supposed to go about testing individual lines of my code? I have the Immediate Tab opened, and have tried following your original instructions but as I've previously explained, I just don't know what to do from here.

Comment: No worries, "hello world" tutorials merrily teach how to pop a `MsgBox` but rarely go over the basic features of the debugger. Hit F9 to toggle a breakpoint on a line of code; F8 to step through, Shift+F8 to step over, and F5 to resume execution - you can invoke the function "manually" from the immediate pane, or have Excel invoke it by invoking it from a worksheet cell.